# How does a GitHub repository's gh-pages branch get created?

Tags: github

I am new to GitHub and I am currently taking and online course for front-end development. I am currently trying to set up my development environment by syncing GitHub and my browser.

When I create a new repository on GitHub and publish my basic webpage it only creates a `master` branch. From what I understand when I create my website a branch called `gh-pages` should also be created.

This is not the case for me. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully, GitHub does not automatically create a `gh-pages` branch for you. Not all projects need a GitHub Pages site.

You can [tell GitHub to publish a Pages site from a (manually-created) `gh-pages` branch, from your `master` branch](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#enabling-github-pages-to-publish-your-site-from-master-or-gh-pages), or [from a `docs/` folder in your `master` branch](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#publishing-your-github-pages-site-from-a-docs-folder-on-your-master-branch) in the **GitHub Pages** → **Source** section in your repository's **Settings**.

Exactly how you create your `gh-pages` branch will depend on the tools you are using. Using the standard Git command-line you can use the [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) or [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) command with its [`-b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnewbranchgtltstartpointgt) option, e.g.

```
git checkout -b gh-pages
```

to create a new `gh-pages` branch and check it out.

Once you've committed some content, make sure to push your new branch go GitHub so your Pages site can use it.